# Channel access denied

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I have added a new organization to my consortium network.
Successfully able to join the channels from the new organization peers.
Now I m trying to get information about my channel using the following command :

```
peer channel getinfo -c my-channel
```

But I get this error as result :

```
Error: received bad response, status 500: access denied for [GetChainInfo][my-channel]: [Failed evaluating policy on signed data during check policy on channel [my-channel] with policy [/Channel/Application/Readers]: [implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Readers' sub-policies to be satisfied]]
```

I get also in peer logs this error:

```
Peer Logs - 2021-10-20 07:18:45.057 UTC [policies] SignatureSetToValidIdentities -> WARN d1a93c invalid identity: certificate subject=CN=peer1,OU=peer,O=Hyperledger,ST=North Carolina,C=US serialnumber=41365438365218511579049 error="MSP Org3 is not defined on channel
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you update the channel to include Org3MSP when running configtxlator. I am presuming that you might have referenced the tutorial on how to add andd join channels.

Comment: I followed this tutorial "https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/channel_update_tutorial.html".

Comment: Before adding Org3MSP to the channel, I signed the new configuration file (org3_update_in_envelope.pb') with all the peers, then I executed the command which allows to update the channel configuration.